# C# Use a ref parameter as an "in-out" parameter to return/swap a reference?

Tags: c#, reference, unsafe

I am having some trouble changing what a reference is... well... referencing.
I come from a C++ backround where I can pass pointers, then change the pointers if I need to change whatever data I want modified.

In C#, a lot of similar functionality can be done using references, but I can't easily change what a reference is associated with. I seem to be stuck "1-layer deep" for references when passed as parameters. I can't seem to have parameters which are "ref ref".
I can have a function return a reference, which allows me to set a local reference and thus change which data I want modified.

However, I have some functions which search for a specific variable and returns a reference to it, but in some cases the variable might not exist. As a return ref cannot ever be null, this means I need to pass the reference with an out parameter ("out", not being the keyword out, but an in-out reference parameter) which can be set to the new found reference or left unchanged if unfound (with the function returning a bool if the value was found).

**So is there a way, without using unsafe code, to use a parameter to pass out a reference?**

Below is a bare-bones demonstration of what I am talking about. Ignore the purpose or better ways to access these members, this is just to demonstrate what I mean by changing a ref parameter or needing to return a null reference in a function which returns a reference.

I am much more used to having direct control over my memory.  A big thanks to anyone who can help!

```
public class my_class
{
    protected float[] array_of_numbers= {1.1f, 2.2f, 3.3f};
    
    // this function will copy the value from the index to out_float_reference_, but not change the actual reference
    protected bool get_float_reference_by_out_parameter(ref float out_float_reference_, in int index_to_find_)
    {
        bool found_= false;
        
        if(index_to_find_ > 0 && index_to_find_ < array_of_numbers.Length)
        {
            found_= true;
            
            out_float_reference_= ref array_of_numbers[index_to_find_];
        }
        
        return found_;
    }
    
    // this function will return an actual reference to the index, but there are situations where there would be nothing to return, and a null is not allowed as a return
    protected ref float get_float_reference_by_return_ref(in int index_to_find_, out bool index_found_)
    {

        index_found_= false;
    
        if(index_to_find_ > 0 && index_to_find_ < array_of_numbers.Length)
        {
            index_found_= true;
            return ref array_of_numbers[index_to_find_];
        }
        else
        {
        // use unsafe code to return a null reference, which is not desired
        }
    }
    
    public void main_method()
    {
        // will work
        ref float first_reference_to_index_found_by_return_reference_= get_float_reference_by_return_ref(0, out bool first_ref_found_);
        
        // will fail, unless unmanged code is used to return a null reference with unsafe code
        ref float second_reference_to_index_found_by_return_reference_= get_float_reference_by_return_ref(99, out bool second_ref_found_);
        
        float local_variable_to_get_index_value_by_reference= default;
        
        // this code accounts for a "null out value", but cannot change the reference of its ref parameter
        bool third_ref_found_= get_float_reference_by_out_parameter(ref local_variable_to_get_index_value_by_reference, 0);
        
        //..... more code for what to do with the references.....
    }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/497

Comment: The whole point of ref-return/ref-local is to have a reference to some _variable_ location. The feature does not allow these references to be invalid, which includes null values. You should use some other mechanism to indicate to the caller that it could not return a value. In your example, IMHO `IndexOutOfRangeException` is a perfect fit. In other cases, returning a tuple with the ref-return value and a bool might work. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_pointer#History for why arguably the C# designers are simply avoid repeating the mistakes of the past.

Comment: See especially http://mustoverride.com/refs-not-ptrs/

Comment: What about `return ref Unsafe.NullRef<float>();` Doesn't work on SharpLab I assume due to their fancy debug visualizers... But works fine locally and on dotnet fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/8nZI7Z that would solve the second case proposed by OP (combined with `Unsafe.IsNullRef<float>`) and it doesn't use any `unsafe` code, which I think solves the intended question and not the asked one

Comment: @pinkfloydx33: _"it doesn't use any unsafe code"_ -- that seems like splitting hairs to me. Yes, it technically works without the `unsafe` keyword in one's own code. But it hardly meets the spirit, and arguably doesn't even meet the literal meaning of, _"doesn't use **any** `unsafe` code"_.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I know, and I don't disagree that it's splitting hairs. But I got the sense OP is looking to do something without the mess, since they mention needing to use pointers and unmanaged code to achieve it, which... they don't (directly anyways) The second example could be turned into a three line method (or a single ternary return), omitting the "found" parameter (relying on IsNullRef in the caller instead)

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 I am currently using ref Unsafe.NullRef<T>(), haha, but I would prefer to use an alternative if one exists. Thank you for the suggestion though! That was my first fix, and it worked, but it goes against the language standards.

Comment: @SeanWagemans right... But it doesn't go against IL which is why such methods exist, particularly for low level types of things. If you don't like it then unfortunately I think you're out of options other than to rethink your design

Comment: @Peter Duniho thanks peter, I will take a look at Tuples. I am trying to find a way to pass references through multiple layers of functions. This can be done by returning a ref. If there is a way to do it using a ref parameter, this would allow me to only ever pass existing variables and account for when a search couldn't find anything (aka nothing is ever null). However, I don't know how to pass a reference out via a parameter, only copy values.  Thats what I need to know (or a similar way of passing a reference)

I will take a look at tuples though, thanks!